# Vala/C Deserialize Array

Tags: c, json, vala

I have data that must be entered with a text file that I pipe in---this is running on my universities server.

I have two doubles, a one dimensional double array, and a two dimensional double matrix. How can I import this into variables?

Many thanks!

Comment: Use `fscanf()`? Am I missing something?

Comment: How do I import an array whose length I am uncertain of?

Comment: @user2195592 Line by line, in first place. `man 3 realloc`.

Comment: You have a json tag… is the file JSON?  In which case, I assume the array is as well?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to come-up with some format that program would recognize and write an extraction.  If it is just for a sake of one program, one can encode arrays like:

```
<num> <num>  # list of dimensions
<num> <num> <num> ...  # array values in the row major order
```

and then in your program you do something like:

```
size_t m, n;
fscanf (f, "%zu %zu", &m, &n);
float (*array)[m][n] = malloc (sizeof (float) * m * n));
for (size_t i = 0; i < m; i++)
  for (size_t j = 0; j < n; j++)
    fscanf (f, "%f", &(*array)[i][j]);
```

This is a bit ugly, as you need to allocate multidimensional array dynamically and refer to it using parentheses, but by doing so you avoid the index computation which you would need to implement by hands otherwise.